# Webkit transitions: multiple properties on Android

Tags: android, css, webkit

This is a fairly specific question, but it generalizes to *running Webkit transitions that affects more than one property*.

I'm trying to use a transition to translate and scale a div in the Android default browser. When the transition ends, the element pops back to its default state. It looks kind of like I forgot to use animation-fill-mode, but on a webkit transition.

The transition is setup to work on -webkit-transform with a translate3d() and a scaleX(). It translates and scales fine, but as soon as the transition ends, it pops back to full size and its "default" position. If I transition on only translated3d or scaleX, it works fine. The webkitTransitionEnd event fires *after* the "pop-back" so I can't intercept the "pop-back" and override it.

Is multiple properties on a Webkit transition something that is known to not work on Android 2.3? Does anyone know of a working example that I could compare to? Any ideas for workarounds?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen no docs or release note about it, but I know from trial and other posts that many of us have not been able to get multiple animations or transforms to work in any Android < 3.0.

see.
http://daneden.me/2011/12/putting-up-with-androids-bullshit/

and comments on.
[CSS3 Multiple transforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8819488/css3-multiple-transforms)