# D3.js - Zoom network graph with canvas and then drag node

Tags: javascript, d3.js, canvas, zooming, drag

I have implemented a network graph using canvas using [this example (Force Layout with Canvas)](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3180395) with functionality to [drag (Circle Dragging II)](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/c206c20294258c18832ff80d8fd395c3) and to [zoom (Canvas geometric zooming)](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3680958) all updated to V4.

The problem is that when I zoom or drag the canvas and applying:

```
canvas.translate(d3.event.translate[0], d3.event.translate[1]);
canvas.scale(d3.event.scale, d3.event.scale);
```

The nodes objects are somehow not updated accordingly. They are drawn just fine before the `canvas.restore();`, but when I try to target a node with the mouse using:

```
function getDragSubject() {
    for (var i = nodes.length - 1, node, x, y; i >= 0; --i) {
        node = nodes[i];
        x = node.x - d3.event.x;
        y = node.y - d3.event.y;

        if (x * x + y * y < radius * radius) return node;
    }
}
```

Nothing happens.

I end up doing this:

```
function getDragSubject() {
    for (var i = nodes.length - 1, node, x, y; i >= 0; --i) {
        node = nodes[i];
        x = node.x * scale + translation[0] - d3.event.x;
        y = node.y * scale + translation[1] - d3.event.y;

        if (x * x + y * y < (radius * scale) * (radius * scale)) return node;
    }
}
```

Saving and adding the translations and scale so that I can properly select them after canvas drag/zoom, but it doesn't seems to be the right way to me. Also when I am redrawing the canvas after dragging I am having issues with the nodes properly positioning.

```
function draw() {
    // draw links
    context.strokeStyle = '#ccc';
    context.beginPath();
    links.forEach(function(d) {
        context.moveTo(d.source.x * scale + translation[0], d.source.y * scale + translation[1]);
        context.lineTo(d.target.x * scale + translation[0], d.target.y * scale + translation[1]);
    });
    context.stroke();

    // draw nodes
    context.fillStyle = 'steelblue';
    context.beginPath();
    nodes.forEach(function(d) {
        context.moveTo(d.x * scale + translation[0], d.y * scale + translation[1]);
        context.arc(d.x * scale + translation[0], d.y * scale + translation[1], radius * scale, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    });
    context.fill();
}
```

Anyway this doesn't look right to me.

Anyone with suggestions about improving or modifying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I guess the solution could be found in this post: [Mouse coordinates don't match after Scaling and Panning canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24883585/mouse-coordinates-dont-match-after-scaling-and-panning-canvas). Draw function shouldn't be updated - stays the same as before.

```
function draw() {
    // draw links
    context.strokeStyle = '#ccc';
    context.beginPath();
    links.forEach(function(d) {
        context.moveTo(d.source.x, d.source.y);
        context.lineTo(d.target.x, d.target.y);
    });
    context.stroke();

    // draw nodes
    context.fillStyle = 'steelblue';
    context.beginPath();
    nodes.forEach(function(d) {
        context.moveTo(d.x, d.y);
        context.arc(d.x, d.y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    });
    context.fill();
}
```

Dragging handler function should be updated:

```
var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();

function onDrag() {
    d3.event.subject.fx = ((d3.event.sourceEvent.pageX - rect.left) - translation[0]) / scale;
    d3.event.subject.fy = ((d3.event.sourceEvent.pageY - rect.top) - translation[1]) / scale;
}
```