# How to find a Coordinate of a point on Image after zoom

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have an Image which gets zoom on mouse wheel.I just want to put an another Image over that Image and I 
want that once i zoom the first image my second image also moves over the same point of image on which it is lying earlier.In Short I want to know the co-ordinate of point of image on zoom.

Comment: Have you any online demo for it?

Comment: you can find fix for this issue [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21717001/html5-canvas-get-coordinates-after-zoom-and-translate